# When using the nth term test on a Alternating Series will it always diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

If you have a alternating series you and put it though the nth term test you split the limit into two parts multiplying each other. One containing (-1)^n and another containing what its multiplied by. But the limit containing (-1)^n will always result in DNE(Does not exist) so if you multiply that by a number whatever the other limit answer is. Would that still be DNE? And would mean that the divergence test(nth term test) always passes with the alternating series since it does not equal 0 and always equals DNE.
[DNE times number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC3zn.png)

I saw some other questions on stack exchange similar but they did not answer my specific question about DNE so that is why I am asking.

Comment: This is hard to follow. Please edit the question to provide some actual *examples* of the process you are describing.  I see you put something in the link, but it would be much better to type up the example(s) directly in the body of the question (a blind person would be unable to read your linked image, for instance).

Comment: The rule "limit of product = product of limits" does not hold unless both limits exist. Considerthe sum of $(-1)^n/n$ which does exist, but using your method would be said to diverge.

Comment: @Kcd How would I type limits in the text and the other math format?

Comment: @GoldenBoy google on "mathjax"

Comment: @GoldenBoy look up how to do typesetting in LaTeX (basically, math expressions go inside a pair of dollar signs, and type \sum_{n \geq 1} inside the dollar signs -- the backslash in front of "sum" is important -- to get the mathematical notation for a sum to appear running over $n \geq 1$).

Comment: This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method of taking limits is not good: you can't legitimately drag "nonsense/does not exist" limits through calculations whenever you want.  If you have a sequence $a_n = b_nc_n$ where $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$ does not exist while $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n$ exits, that does *not* mean $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ does not exist.

**Example**. Let $a_n = (-1)^n/n^2$, with $b_n = (-1)^n$ and $c_n = 1/n^2$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$ does not exist, $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = 0$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$.

**Example**.  Let $a_n = 1/n = n/n^2$, with $b_n = n$ and $c_n = 1/n^2$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = 0$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$.

**Example**.  Let $a_n = 1 = n/n$, with $b_n = n$ and $c_n = 1/n$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = 0$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 1$.

Comment: So does not exist multiplied by 0 equals 0 for a limit. And would DNE multiplied a number would be just DNE?

Comment: Consider $b_n = (-1)^nn$ and $c_n = 1/n$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$ does not exist and $\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = 0$, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_nc_n$ does not exist.  Zero is a number, so your "number" was meant to be "nonzero number".  I suggest that *you* think about your second question (hint: if $c_n \to L$ where $L \not= 0$ then $1/c_n \to 1/L$).  You need to learn not to treat "DNE" as if it is a legitimate mathematical object that interacts with things as numbers do, just as $\infty$ isn't either: how a limit equal to $\infty$ interacts with limit $0$ *depends on the situation*.

Comment: Ok I better understand now, so I should instead so simplifying the first limit to DNE then using that to multiply by something. I should instead not evaluate it to DNE and leave it as is then multiply it by the other limit and see how the whole limit works and then evaluate it.

Comment: @GoldenBoy yes, that is a better approach.